# Saving more than one entity at once

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm working with Entity Framework 5 and a MySQL DB and I'd like to save two new related entities at once:

```
            var record = data.Records.Create();
            record.Name = "Abbey Road";
            data.Records.Add(record);

            // Create the song
            var song = data.Songs.Create();
            song.Title = "Here Comes The Sun";
            song.Record = record;
            data.Songs.Add(song);

            data.SaveChanges();
```

But it fails. The exception is:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : Fehler beim Aktualisieren der Einträge. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der internen Ausnahme.
>     ----> System.Data.UpdateException : Fehler beim Aktualisieren der Einträge. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der internen Ausnahme.
>     ----> System.ArgumentException : Der angegebene Wert ist keine Instanz eines gültigen Konstantentyps.
>   Parametername: value

English Translation

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: Failed to update the entries. See the inner exception. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: failed to update the entries. See the inner exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: value specified is not a valid constant type an instance. Parameter name: value

Sorry, it's German. The first exception means the given value is not a valid type of constant. It looks like that the provider (mysql) wants to update something where it should use an insert.

Does anybody have an idea what it is?

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of similar problems in combination with mySQL. Try change any unsigned columns in mysql to **signed**. EF doesn't support unsigned.

Hope this helps